# deploying web app in ubuntu

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-server

I have a project in VM ubuntu and I want to run it on localhost but I get

[image]

I have stored the project in `var/www/html` because when I check in terminal this one shows

[image]

How to properly deploy in ubuntu localhost?

Comment: Is there an index.html inside of /egov?

Comment: yes.. i think my mistake is that i just created that folder where can i find the var folder in ubuntu that is for localhost. that folder i have is i just created it in home page maybe this is the reason? @wilsonhobbs

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your content in the `~/var/www/html`. However, you need your code to be in the root directory, in `/var/www`. Just run `sudo cp -r ~/var/www/html /var/www/html` in your terminal.

Comment: can you tell me what will happened if i do the command above i would like to know what it does so i will learn.

Comment: `cp` is a bash command that will copy a file from the first path to the second one. `-r` is a flag that specifies you're copying a directory, and will copy the entire folder. You can also substitute `mv` which will move the files, instead of duplicating them.

Comment: i see i make multiple copy i think i should first create a folder in second parameter like /var/www/html/egov? i tried running `sudo cp ir ~/var/www/html /var/ww/html` then the egov is inside html making the path var/ww/hrml/html i tried `sudo cp ir ~/var/www/html /var/ww/html/egov` but the folder egov is also inside egov.. i want var/www/html/egov/index